# alias does not work after qsub

Tags: r, bash, qsub

I installed R under my home folder, and I would like to use the new R is invoked when I submit jobs to clusters. The cluster nodes all have CentOS installed.

Here is the configure I made in the .bash_profile and .bashrc:

```
if [ `lsb_release -i|cut -c17-20` == 'Cent' ] ; then
    alias R='/home/XXX/R-3.0.2/bin/R'
    alias Rscript='/home/XXX/R-3.0.2/bin/Rscript'
fi
```

I added following in .bash_profile:

```
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
    source ~/.bashrc
fi
```

I also added this to the scripts submitted.

```
source $HOME/.bash_profile
```

I tried with qsub -I, it works perfect.

However, after I submit the job, and `which R` still show the original path!

How to set the environment correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aliasing doesn't affect the `which` command, for example:

```
$ which R
/usr/bin/R
$ alias R=/bin/date
$ R
Sun Jan  5 13:40:54 CET 2014      # as you see the alias works
$ which R                         # `which R` still returns the original path
/usr/bin/R
```

Instead of using aliases, I think you want to prepend `/home/XXX/R-3.0.2/bin` to `PATH`:

```
PATH="/home/XXX/R-3.0.2/bin:$PATH"
```

After this, if `R` and `Rscript` exist in `/home/XXX/R-3.0.2/bin`, then:

- `which R` should return `/home/XXX/R-3.0.2/bin/R`
- `which Rscript` should return `/home/XXX/R-3.0.2/bin/Rscript`

as they will be found in `/home/XXX/R-3.0.2/bin` first, before any other directory in the rest of `$PATH`.

Comment: Thanks @janos. I made a .env file and added PATH="/home/XXX/R-3.0.2/bin:$PATH" in it, then source the file if it detect the CentOs in the if command.